# Ordering on the unit hypercubes $[0,1]^n$

Tags: geometry, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory

I would like to establish an ordering on the hypercubes $[0,1]^n$ for $0 \leq n \leq K$. This means finding a function $V(n): \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that we have a strict ordering $V(0) < V(1) < \cdots < V(K)$.

This ordering should

(1) capture my intuition that the cube is bigger than the square, and the square is bigger than the line. For example the cube needs more vertices for its representation than the square.

(2) capture the exponential growth of the hypercubes. For example the sampling density is defined as $M^{1/n}$, with $M$ being the number of samples, n the dimension. To sustain a constant sampling density $M^{1/n}=c$ we therefore need $M = e^{n log(c)}$ samples, which scales exponentially.

Unfortunately, the n-dimensional Lebesgue measure is $V(n) = 1$. The $K$-th dimensional Lebesgue measure is $V(n<K) = 0$ and $V(K)=1$. This does not establish a strict ordering.

I know of three ways to establish a strict ordering on the hypercubes,

(1) computing the longest diagonal in
n-dimensions which is $V_1(n) = \sqrt{n}$,

(2) computing the number of vertices
of the cube which is $V_2(n) = 2^n$,

(3) discretizing the cube with
some resolution $\Delta$, such that each dimension contains $M = 1/\Delta$ points. Then the size will be $V_3(n) = M^n$

The first two ways do not capture the exponential growth
of the hypercube, while the third way depends on an arbitrary parameter, such
that $V_3$ could either grow too fast or too slow.

Does anyone know of a better way to establish an ordering between
unit hypercubes? Is there a generalization of measures for such a case?

EDIT: clarified the "size" issue raised in the comments

Comment: It's far from clear what, if anything, your intuitive "size" means.

Comment: A cube doesn't contain more area than a square. A square doesn't contain more length than a line. Your idea of size doesn't seem to match any reasonable or relevant measure of the space in each dimension, so comparing them or extending the concept to higher dimensions is similarly unclear.

Comment: This is a great question. In geometric measure theory, there are a bunch of generalized invariants like intrinsic volume, spread, and magnitude that could be relevant to your interests.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Ok let me try another way: Let us look at the volume of the line, the plane and the cuboid in $R^3$. In $R^3$, the measure of the line is $v_1 = V_1(0 \times 0 \times [0,1]) = 0$, of the plane is $v_2 = V_2(0 \times [0,1]^2) = 0$, and of the cube is $v_3 = V([0,1]^3) = 1$. So line and plane would be both zero-measure volumes. But they are clearly different, for example the same number of samples drawn at random from them would give different sampling densities, implying that the sets are different. So how could i quantify this difference?

Comment: @ChrisCulter intrinsic volume seems interesting, thanks, i will look into that

Comment: @Nij Yes that is true. Basically, i don't know how to define size here, in $R^3$, the line is represented by 2 vertices and 1 edge, the square by 4 vertices, 4 edges and 1 face, and the cube by 8 vertices, 12 edges, 6 faces, and 1 cell. So they differ if we count their elements, the question would be how we could attach a meaningful number to quantify this difference.

Comment: Does it have to be a *single* number? Volumes in different dimensions are hard to compare, but it might be easier to measure each cube at each dimension, starting with the vertices at dimension $0$ up to infinity. So a point would be $(1,0,\ldots)$, a line $(2,1,0,\ldots)$, a square $(4,4,1,0,\ldots)$, a cube $(8,12,6,1,0,\ldots)$, a tesseract $(16,32,24,8,1,0,\ldots)$ and so on. You could compare these vectors lexicographically, or by a linear projection to a line in a direction of your choice, or similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best I have come up with so far:
Any n-cube can be decomposed into a set of elements, i.e. [a set of m-cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube#Elements) , for example the cube in 3d is decomposed of 1 3-cube (cell), 6 2-cube (faces), 12 1-cubes (edges) and 8 0-cubes (vertices). As @MvG pointed out in the comments, we can compare cubes by comparing their elements. 
The number of m-cubes inside an n-cube is given by the formula
$$E_{m,n} = 2^{m-n}\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$$
To each m-cube we can assign a value of $m$, such that we can assign to each n-cube the sum of its m-cubes times m as
$$V(n) = \sum\limits_{m=0}^n m\cdot E_{m,n}$$

We obtain 
$$\begin{align*}
n   \ :\ & 0 < 1 < 2 < 3\ \ < 4\ \ \  < \cdots\\
V(n)\ :\ & 0 < 1 < 6 < 21 < 108 < \cdots
\end{align*}
$$

This is equivalent to the sequence $a(n)=(n-1)3^{n-2}$ ([A027471](https://oeis.org/A027471))